# Ошибка Bad Request Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, vps

Имеется домен example.me и VPS на vscale.io. При переходе по доменному имени получаю 400. Конфиг nginx-а:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.me;

  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

  error_log /path/to/error.log debug;
  access_log /path/to/access.log;

  location /static/ { ... }
  ...
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

Пробовал выставлять большие значения **large_client_header_buffers**.
В чем может быть проблема?

**UPD:**
`error.log`

```
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http cleanup add: 0000563214C45340
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 get rr peer, try: 1
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 stream socket 7
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 epoll add connection: fd:7 ev:80002005
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 connect to 0.0.0.0:8000, fd:7 #182
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream connect: -2
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 posix_memalign: 0000563214C38CC0:128 @16
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 event timer add: 7: 60000:1489263889995
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http finalize request: -4, "/?" a:1, c:2
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http request count:2 blk:0
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http run request: "/?"
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/"
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream recv(): -1 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream request: "/?"
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream send request handler
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream send request
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream send request body
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 chain writer buf fl:1 s:438
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 chain writer in: 0000563214C45378
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 writev: 438 of 438
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 event timer del: 7: 1489263889995
    2017/03/11 23:23:49 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 event timer add: 7: 60000:1489263889995
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream request: "/?"
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http upstream process header
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 malloc: 0000563214C45A50:4096
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 recv: fd:7 134 of 4096
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http proxy status 400 "400 Bad Request"
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http proxy header: "Server: gunicorn/19.7.0"
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http proxy header: "Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2017 20:23:50 GMT"
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html"
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 http proxy header done
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 xslt filter header
    2017/03/11 23:23:50 [debug] 13703#13703: *180 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

`access.log`:

```
<ip> - - [11/Mar/2017:13:08:17 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-""Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
<ip> - - [11/Mar/2017:13:08:17 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
<ip> - - [11/Mar/2017:13:08:58 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
<ip> - - [11/Mar/2017:13:25:21 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan error.log при этом пуст

Comment: Значит скорее всего не в nginx проблема, смотрите логи сайта

Comment: А если запустить на 80 то, что у вас на 8000, без nginx, то получается обратиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим образом:
1) Изменил **proxy_pass** на **http://0.0.0.0:8001/** соответственно gunicorn запускаю на 0.0.0.0:8001
2) Убедился, что в **settings.py** в **ALLOWED_HOSTS** именно мое доменное имя

Comment: А почему это помогло? В settings.py был другой хост? И какая принципиальная разница между 8000 и 8001?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov точно сказать не могу, возможно на 8000 порту могло что-то помимо крутиться. А про ALLOWED_HOSTS для потомков добавил, в процессе гугления натыкался и на такой способ решения проблемы, может кому-то пригодится.